# How to get the process name in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How do I get the process name from a PID using C++ in Windows?

Answer (score 29):

I guess the [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx) function should help, given that *your* process possesses the necessary rights. Once you obtain a handle to the process, you can use the [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198.aspx) function to obtain full path (path to the .exe file) of the process.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "psapi.h"
// Important: Must include psapi.lib in additional dependencies section
// In VS2005... Project > Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE Handle = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE,
        8036 /* This is the PID, you can find one from windows task manager */
    );
    if (Handle) 
    {
        TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];
        if (GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle, 0, Buffer, MAX_PATH))
        {
            // At this point, buffer contains the full path to the executable
        }
        else
        {
            // You better call GetLastError() here
        }
        CloseHandle(Handle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know how to get a PID in the first place, though this is not asked by the OP.

Comment: @Jaywalker A wmi call and the win32_process class will do the trick

Comment: @Jaywalker: You can use EnumProcesses (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629.aspx)

Comment: Instead of including psapi.lib in additional dependencies section you can just do a #pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")

Comment: To get the process id from a HWND you can use `DWORD processId; GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId);`.

Comment: I used the method as described above, and it only works on some processes. Some processes (Such as system ones) don't return a name. Any pointers on how to get those remaining names?

Comment: I use the following line to get the name of current program: GetModuleFileNameEx((HANDLE)-1, 0, Buffer, BUFSIZE);

Comment: It looks like (at least on the win11) it is enough to use just PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right, without PROCESS_VM_READ. So, there would be less chance to get the "access denied" error.

Answer (score 15):

You can obtain the process name by using the WIN32 API [GetModuleBaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683196(v=vs.85).aspx) after having the process handle.  You can get the process handle by using [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx).

To get the executable name you can also use [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 13):

All the above methods require psapi.dll to be loaded ([Read the remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa#remarks)) and iterating through process snapshot is an option one should not even consider for getting a name of the executable file from an efficiency standpoint.

The best approach, even according to MSDN recommendation, is to use [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamea).

```
std::string ProcessIdToName(DWORD processId)
{
    std::string ret;
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        processId /* This is the PID, you can find one from windows task manager */
    );
    if (handle)
    {
        DWORD buffSize = 1024;
        CHAR buffer[1024];
        if (QueryFullProcessImageNameA(handle, 0, buffer, &buffSize))
        {
            ret = buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error GetModuleBaseNameA : %lu", GetLastError());
        }
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error OpenProcess : %lu", GetLastError());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get the executable image name of a given process, take a look at [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: GetModuleFileName doesn't take PID in consideration. It just gives the fully-qualified path for the file that contains the specified module.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the enumprocess functions in the tool help library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629(v=vs.85).aspx

Good example @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this function :

```
std::wstring GetProcName(DWORD aPid)
{ 
 PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);
    HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
      std::wcout  << "can't get a process snapshot ";
      return 0;
    }

    for(BOOL bok =Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);bok;  bok = Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo))
    {
        if( aPid == processInfo.th32ProcessID)
        {
            std::wcout << "found running process: " << processInfo.szExeFile;
            CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
            return processInfo.szExeFile;
        }

    }
    std::wcout << "no process with given pid" << aPid;
    CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
    return std::wstring();
}
```

Comment: Very slow solution