# how to get the process name from the PID in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, process, posix, pid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Process Name in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570174/how-to-get-process-name-in-c)

I am looking for a way to to get the process name from the PID?

I need to translate process id (PID) to process name

any idea?

Comment: What platform (Linux or Windows or...) are you on ?

Comment: You should add the tag posix or windows, pid is not in the c++ standard.

Comment: There is a strong argument that the PID is the process's name. The information you are after is the name of the executable that was run to create the process. That said, your question is clear enough, though thlanguage used is somewhat imprecise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on the used platform like Yahia mentioned in his comment.

on linux: you can get the command-line by reading that file: `/proc/[PID]/cmdline`

on windows: I've found this: [get process name from process id (win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102569/get-process-name-from-process-id-win32)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can open the process using [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to get a handle to the process. After that you can get the process name with [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and close the handle ([CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).