# Internet Explorer Toolbar issue

Tags: internet-explorer, com-interop, toolbar, ieaddon

I'm developing an add-on toolbar for Internet Explorer based on [pretty IE toolbar in c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29215/Pretty-IE-Toolbar-in-C) .. But, while trying i found that this toolbar is getting showed up in File Browser also.. How to make it enabled(or Visible) only in Internet explorer....

Answer (score 1):

You can [get the process name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570174/how-to-get-process-name-in-c) then return E_FAIL from DllGetClassObject() if it isn't iexplore.exe.