# C#, WPF Getting active window

Tags: c#, wpf, user32

After many searches, I can't find a way to get the active window (on windows desktop) or even all visible windows.
All user32 methods have problems :

- `GetForegroundWindow` gets the topmost if there is one.
- `GetActiveWindow` only works for windows inside my app.
- `IsWindowVisible` return true for windows opened but hidden by other windows.
- `GetFocus` only works if there is input field.

How can I do ?

Comment: you want to get other apps active windows?

Comment: Take a look on this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302647/553825

Comment: @ahmedmohamed yes I need the active window even if it is of another app

Comment: What do you want to do with the window? Have you looked at UIA? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Comment: @AliBahrami the answer uses GetForegroundWindow which returns the topmost window...

Comment: @DaveM I just need to get the window title. Sorry I'm a bit new to c# and I don't understand how to use UIA, is it integrated with windows sdk or I need to import a package or something ?

Comment: Built into .Net framework, just add references to the client libraries. It’s not the cleanest API, but it will easily do what you need without resorting to PInvoke.

Comment: There are also tools available for inspecting the UIA tree