# Get Parent Process Name (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

I am trying to get the name of the parent process (full path) in a Windows Console application (C/C++). It looks like it should work, but it is failing and I can't see what I am doing wrong. It is successfully getting the parent PID, but failing on getting the name. Any corrections would be appreciated.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

DWORD getParentPID(DWORD pid)
{
    HANDLE h = NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { 0 };
    DWORD ppid = 0;
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if( Process32First(h, &pe)) 
    {
        do 
        {
            if (pe.th32ProcessID == pid) 
            {
                ppid = pe.th32ParentProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while( Process32Next(h, &pe));
    }
    CloseHandle(h);
    return (ppid);
}

int getProcessName(DWORD pid, PUCHAR fname, DWORD sz)
{
    HANDLE h = NULL;
    int e = 0;
    h = OpenProcess
    (
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        pid
    );
    if (h) 
    {
        if (GetModuleFileNameEx(h, NULL, fname, sz) == 0)
            e = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
    else
    {
        e = GetLastError();
    }
    return (e);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    DWORD pid, ppid;
    int e;
    char fname[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    ppid = getParentPID(pid);
    e = getProcessName(ppid, fname, MAX_PATH);
    printf("PPID=%d Err=%d EXE={%s}\n", ppid, e, fname);
}
```

---

Additional information:
OpenProcess is returning 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). If I add PROCESS_VM_READ as suggested, it returns 299 (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY). I can open the current process, but not the parent process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the process name in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570174/how-to-get-the-process-name-in-c)

Comment: What is failing, exactly? Call to OpenProcess (what is the value of `h`) or GetModuleFileNameEx (what is the value of `e`)?

Comment: Thanks for reply - see Additional Information.

Comment: @Mekap - that is where some of the code is from. I can get the name of the current process, but not the name of the parent process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `OpenProcess` with additional `PROCESS_VM_READ` flag and it should work:

```
h = OpenProcess
    (
    PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
    FALSE,
    pid
    );
```

Also look at the possible duplicate mentioned by Mekap

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. If I include PROCESS_VM_READ I get error 299 (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY) from OpenProcess. Otherwise I get error 5.

Comment: Take a look at the comments in [GetModuleFileNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN documentation: on 64 bit systems this functions returns `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` if a _32-bit_ process requests information about a _64-bit_ process. In this case you should either use `QueryProcessFullImageName()` (Vista and up) or `GetProcessImageFileName()` (XP and up).

Comment: GetProcessImageFileName was the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On Windows Vista+ you can use [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `GetModuleFileNameEx`. `OpenProcess` then only needs to be called with the less privileged `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` flag.