# How to give a program's Handle to a process it created?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have two programs, `Parent` and `Kid`

I want Kid to get the Handle of Parent after Parent creates Kid using `CreateProcess`.  The easiest way to transmit this handle seems to be by putting the Handle in the commandline arguments of `CreateProcess`, but there is no way I can see to get the Parent's Handle inside Parent.  `GetCurrentProcess` returns a weird non-value, and `DuplicateHandle` doesn't work without having the Kid's Handle (Impossible, since I need to create the Kid to get a Handle to it, but `CreateProcess` is also the only chance to send the Parent's Handle to the Kid).

Is there any way I can give `Kid` it's `Parent's` Handle easily?

Comment: Probably an easier way to do this, but you should be able to get (`GetProcessId`) and pass the process ID to the child and then get a handle for the process ID (`OpenProcess`).

Comment: This Q&A should get you really close without having to pass anything: [Get Parent Process Name (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939893/get-parent-process-name-windows)

Comment: @user4581301 you need to use `GetCurrentProcessId()` instead of `GetProcessId()`.

Comment: I figured there had to be a function for that. Oddly it didn't pop up in the first few pages of whatever I used to google.

Comment: Make the handle inheritable. Then the system will dup it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The easiest way to transmit this handle seems to be by putting the Handle in the commandline arguments of `CreateProcess`

That is *one* way to do it, but it is not the *only* way.

Another simple way is to have `Parent` send its process ID from `GetCurrentProcessId()` to `Kid`, and then `Kid` can use `OpenProcess()` to get a handle to `Parent`.

> there is no way I can see to get the Parent's Handle inside Parent.

`GetCurrentProcess()`, which returns a pseudo-handle representing the calling process.  All APIs that accept a process handle will accept this pseudo-handle when used in the context of the calling process.

But, for purposes of passing the calling process's handle to another process, `Parent` would have to use `DuplicateHandle()` to convert the pseudo-handle into a real handle (set `Parent` as both source and target process). This is documented behavior.

> `GetCurrentProcess` returns a weird non-value, and `DuplicateHandle` doesn't work without having the Kid's Handle

After `Parent` has duplicated the pseudo-handle from `GetProcessHandle()` into a real handle, it can then pass that duplicate to `Kid` on the command line.  Just make sure the duplicate is inheritable, and then use `bInheritHandles=TRUE` in the `CreateProcess()` call, or pass a `STARTUPINFOEX` to `CreateProcess()` containing a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` (see [Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873)).

> Impossible, since I need to create the Kid to get a Handle to it

If you don't want to use inheritable handles, then `Parent` can alternatively create `Kid` without passing any handle on the command line, then duplicate the `GetCurrentProcess()` pseudo-handle with `Kid` as the target process, then use an IPC mechanism of your choosing to send the duplicate to `Kid` after it is already running.

> but `CreateProcess` is also the only chance to send the Parent's Handle to the Kid

No, it is not the *only* way.  IPC is another way.

Comment: *send its process ID* in general case need special check, after we open process by this ID, that this is true parent, but not new process, which reuse it ID, after parent exit. very low probability case of course

Comment: @RbMm Yes, very low, if `Parent` doesn't exit before `Kid` has opened the ID (especially if `Parent` waits for `Kid` to exit).

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the parent PID from its own process handle:

```
DWORD pid = GetProcessId(Parent);
```

Then in the child, given the pid, get the handle back:

```
OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pid);
```

The PID can easily be passed around since its a number.

See the following for more details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess

Comment: What you have there reads rather circular. It uses a handle to the parent to get the  parent's pid and then uses the pid to get a handle for the parent. I think you should split this code block up so that it's clear that both lines need to be called by different programs (line 1 by parent and line 2 by child.

Comment: `Parent` can use `GetCurrentProcessId()` and then pass the ID to `Kid`

Answer (score 0):

first of all we need get process id of parent process in Kid. this can be done by call [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) with `ProcessBasicInformation`. and inside `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` (this structure declared in *ntddk.h* ) exist `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` member. strictly say this is can be not parent process id in case you use [`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute) when create Kid, but if you not use this attribute when call `CreateProcess` - the `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` - this will be your parent process id.

than we need understand, that parent can terminated and after this new process start with the same id. so after we open process with `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` we need check that this is really parent, but not new process, created after parent exit and reusing this id. this can be done by query process start time - obviously if this not parent process it started already after parent exit (before this id can not be reused), and parent exit after he start kid. so `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` can be not parent only in case it create time >= kid create time. we can query process create time by `ProcessTimes` with `NtQueryInformationProcess`. so final code can be:

```
NTSTATUS OpenParent(PHANDLE phProcess, ULONG DesiredAccess)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    KERNEL_USER_TIMES kut, _kut;
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;

    NTSTATUS status;

    if (0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(
        NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessBasicInformation, 
        &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0)) && 
        0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(
        NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessTimes, 
        &kut, sizeof(kut), 0)))
    {

        static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa) };
        CLIENT_ID cid = { (HANDLE)pbi.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId };
        if (0 <= (status = NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, DesiredAccess|
            PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &zoa, &cid)))
        {

            if (0 > (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(
                hProcess, ProcessTimes, &_kut, sizeof(_kut), 0)) || 
                kut.CreateTime.QuadPart <= _kut.CreateTime.QuadPart)
            {
                NtClose(hProcess);
                return STATUS_PROCESS_IS_TERMINATING;
            }

            *phProcess = hProcess;
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```