# How to get application name by using pid in dart-win32

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows, psapi

I'm trying to get currently active application's name on windows flutter app using pid. Is there any way to get the app's name by process id?
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart' as win;

void main(){
    ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint32> pidPointer = calloc();
    int hwnd = win.GetForegroundWindow();
    win.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pidPointer);
    int pid = pidPointer.value;
    print('Process ID of the active window: $pid');
    win.free(pidPointer);
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570174/how-to-get-the-process-name-in-c

Comment: Yes. This is informative. But I'm looking for simpler method. I'm newbies in native code.

Comment: Not sure how much easier it could be... `package:win32` provides the 2 necessary methods, e.g. https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/GetModuleFileNameEx.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';

void getActiveAppName() {
    ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint32> pidPointer = calloc();
    int hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pidPointer);
    int pid = pidPointer.value;
    free(pidPointer);
    printModules(pid);
}
int printModules(int processID) {
    // Print the process identifier.
    //print('\nProcess ID: $processID');

    // Get a handle to the process.
    final hProcess = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID);

    if (hProcess == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Get a list of all the modules in this process.
    final hMods = calloc<HMODULE>(1024);
    final cbNeeded = calloc<DWORD>();

    if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, ffi.sizeOf<HMODULE>() * 1024, cbNeeded) ==
        1) {
            final szModName = wsalloc(MAX_PATH);
            final hModule = hMods.elementAt(0).value;
            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hModule, szModName, MAX_PATH) != 0) {
                final hexModuleValue = hModule
                    .toRadixString(16)
                    .padLeft(ffi.sizeOf<HMODULE>(), '0')
                    .toUpperCase();
                // Print the module name and handle value.
                print('\t${szModName.toDartString().split('\\').last.split('.exe').first.split('.EXE').first}'); // (0x$hexModuleValue)
            }
            free(szModName);
    }
    free(hMods);
    free(cbNeeded);

    // Release the handle to the process.
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```